# Change background color of a card when the element in the card is being focused

Tags: antd

I am using Ant Design and I am new to it. In my case, there are many input components inside a card component. I would like to change the card background color when any input component inside the card is being focused.

I would like to see if there is a simple way to do so, or I have to write JavaScript functions for this case.

I am appreciate with any help on this case. It is grateful if any sample code can be provided. Thank you very much.

P.S. I am able to change the background color of the card. But I cannot find any API on card component which provide this kind of function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS trick like following

**CSS**

```
.highlight:focus-within {
     background: #a1c084;
}
```

**JS**

```
<Card title="Card Name" className="hightlight">
     <Input placeholder="Your Input" />
</Card>
```

I hope this would help

Code Pen : https://codepen.io/shreyans-shrivastav/pen/LawoYE